# How load data from Cassandra to Colaboratory

Tags: cassandra, google-colaboratory

I have a local installation of Cassandra DB, where I' store some data.
I need to load this data in Google Colaboratory. Is it possibile? How you do it?

I have tried the code that I have utilized in PyCharm to import data from Cassandra, but it does not work. The code is the following:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster=Cluster(['127.0.0.1'],port=9042) 

session = cluster.connect()
```

The following error occurs:

> NoHostAvailable                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 2
> 3 cluster=Cluster(['127.0.0.1'],port=9042)
> ----> 4 session = cluster.connect()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal()
>
> NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
> ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1',
> 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you encounter?

Comment: I think the way I tried is completely wrong, so I did not post it.